# iOS Development: What's an easy way to generate an unlock code from a string that can be validated in the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm diving into iOS development and I just built my first game.  Since Apple controls all the In-App purchases, they make it difficult for me to provide my customers with free content if I so choose.  As such, I'd like to be able to email a single customer a single unlock code they can use to unlock an In-App purchase, but that code can only be used by that one single customer and I won't have any kind of a server to validate it.  So my idea is to have the user email me their Game Center username and I use that to generate the code and add a check in my app to limit the number of unlocks to one per app (that way they can't just create a bunch of Game Center accounts and unlock all the IAPs).

What's an easy way to generate an unlock code from a string (in this case, their Game Center username) that can be validated in the app?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

****UPDATE**** The simplest solution to this is to use the `hash` method of the `NSString` class.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question, provide a reason. I don't see anything wrong with it personally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do some sort of hash.  You can read up on doing an MD5 hash.  This lets you generate a unique code from any string.  A good strategy could be to make a string that is a combination of a username and device id (UUID which can be accessed programmatically).  Have your app generate the code and mail from within the app.  There probably several other ways to accomplish this too.

Comment: Ahh combination of username and UDID is a good idea! I'll looking into MD5 hash, thank you!

Comment: So I just found the "hash" method of the NSString class, which seems like a simple enough solution to all this.

Comment: I wrote a little php script with a Obejctive-c wrapper to send emails from withing an application without using the MFMailComposeViewController. Write me an email if you are interested. ;-) It's not yet an OpenSource project, but I'll make one out of it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that sort of unlock code is pretty much the same as license key tied to a username. In that case, this article might be of interest:

[OpenSSL for License Keys](http://sigpipe.macromates.com/2004/09/05/using-openssl-for-license-keys/) by Alan Odgaard.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't do this. IAP (unless something has changed that I don't know about) doesn't work with promotional codes. (Also, if you're planning on doing this for more than a couple customers, then it wouldn't work anyway, since you get a limited number of promotional codes per app version).

But nothing's stopping you from providing your own free content outside of IAP! Apple has no problem with providing extra free content inside your app. But the point is that if you are also selling it with IAP, you need to be sure that the user isn't paying for it somewhere else, and then getting it for free (since then, Apple will see that you're circumventing their cut of the purchase).

If you do go this route, you'll probably want to have some sort of server where you can check and redeem users' requests for free content. Urban Airship may have something along these lines, I think.

Comment: Thanks, Johnathan, tho I didn't mean Apple promotional codes, I mean my own promotional codes. In fact, forget the word "Promotional" entirely, its causing confusion.  How can I generate a unique code from the user's Game Center username that can be validated by my app?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/introducing-mkstorekit-%E2%80%93-version-3/). You can allow certain UUIDs to have free access to iAPs.